# yes or no to exit a switch statement

Tags: c

Is it possible to create yes or no function to be called to exit a `switch` statement. if (y)es is hit it would exit. If (n)o is hit it would loop back to the switch's options. if so how would this be done. This is what I have so far.

I hope this helps to clarify what I am trying to do

```
int yes_no(void) {

    scanf("%d", &option);

    while (option == 'y' || option == 'Y' || option == 'n' || option == 'N') {
        if (option == 'y' || option == 'Y') {
            return 1;
        } else
        if (option == 'n' || option == 'N') {
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable");
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int select;

    do {
        printf("0 exit");
        printf("1 hello");

        scanf("%d", &select);

        switch (select) {
          case 0:
            printf("Exit the program? (Y)es or (N)o :");
            yes_no(); // if (n)o is hit it will loop back to the menu
            break;
          case 1:
            printf("hello how r u doing");
            break;
          default:
            printf("not accepted number");
        }
    } while (select != 0);
}
```

Comment: `return 0;` -> `continue;`

Comment: There is not switch statement in your code, you should use one.

Comment: I'm sure what you want to accomplish can be done easily, but not necessarily the way you describe (I think... it's not very clear).  What do you actually want your program to do?  Loop, performing user-selected actions, until the user says to stop?

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following `yes_no` function.

```
int yes_no() {
  char option;

  while (1) {
    printf("(y/n): ");
    if (scanf(" %c", &option) != 1) {
      printf("Error occurred while reading option.\n");
      continue;
    }

    if (option == 'y' || option == 'Y') {
      return 1;
    } else if (option == 'n' || option == 'N') {
      return 0;
    } else {
      printf("Only (y)es or (n)o are acceptable.\n");
    }
  }
}
```

You have a return value of `1` if given a `yes` input, and `0` in case of `no`. With this in mind, in the `case 0` code block of the `switch` statement, the return value of this function can be captured, which can then be used to either break the loop or do nothing. For example:

```
int main(void) {
  int select;
  int continue_loop = 1;

  printf("Press 0 to exit\n");
  printf("Press 1 for hello\n\n");

  while (continue_loop) {
    printf("(0/1): ");
    if (scanf(" %d", &select) != 1) {
      printf("Error occurred while reading number.\n");
      continue;
    }

    switch (select) {
      case 0:
        printf("Exit the program? (y)es or (n)o;\n");
        int make_sure = yes_no();  // yes_no() returns 1 if 'yes', and 0 if 'no'
        // If 'yes', break while loop by setting continue_loop to 0.
        // Do nothing in case of 'no'
        if (make_sure == 1) {
          continue_loop = 0;
        }
        break;
      case 1:
        printf("Hello, how are you doing?\n");
        break;
      default:
        printf("Number not accepted.\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, if I get your question correctly:

```
int yes_or_no()
{
  do
  {
    char option = 0;
    scanf(" %c", &option);
    if (option == 'y' || option == 'Y')
      return 1;
    if (option == 'n' || option == 'N')
      return 0;
    printf("Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable");
  }
  while( 1 );
}
```

Comment: I think you should test the code first. What happens if you input something that is not handled in the `if` statements?

Comment: Oh, ok, that's why the downvote... Well, of course, it's not bullet proof, but as you might now, handling efficiently user input is not a trivial task. But I don't think that it was what the OP was asking for, he  seemed to be asking just for some basic stuff. But, go ahead, post some bullet proof user-input handling, I'll upvote.

Comment: Either remove the `while` loop or prevent the infinite loop by fixing the identifier. Also, don't be like that. I just want you to improve your answer, nothing else.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to post an answer, maybe you can edit my answer and fix it to improve it? Go ahead.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi This loop would only be infinite if `scanf()` fails (like on EOF or something), or valid input is never entered.  It will print the message for every invalid character including whitespace, though.

Answer (score 0):

with switch you can perform your code better:

```
int yes_no(void) {
scanf("%d", &option);
while (1){
switch(option){
case 'y':
case 'Y':
return 1;
case 'n':
case 'N':
return 0;
default:
printf("invalid input.try again");
scanf("%d", &option);
}
}
}
```